# Retrieve data form inner list using java8 stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have List of Employees , each employee has list of Departments in it. I want to get the list department under a single employee. Here is my code ,

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
List<Department> departments = employeeList.stream().filter(x-> x.getEmployeeName().equals("XXX")).filter(y -> y.getDepartmets()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

can someone help ?

Answer (score 5):

```
employeeList.stream()
            .filter(x -> "XXX".equals(x.getEmployeeName()))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Employee::getDepartmets)     
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

First `filter` by name and get the first one found. If present map it to those departments, else produce an empty list.

Comment: great it worked. thank you so much for your response.

Comment: have come across such implementation while trying out code myself either, but one question that puzzles me is *Why not `map` using `Stream` instead of `map`ping based on `Optional`?

Comment: @aruntheimperfect you could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it helped

Comment: @nullpointer in cases like this it's a matter of choice. I can't seem to think of a scenario where they would behave differently. IMO I'd favour this approach as the `findFirst` is as close up to the `filter` operation as possible making it easier to figure out what's going on.